# promises: unhandled exception not caught

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird, unhandled-exception

I have got an authentication method which you can find below. Within that method I am calling different Joi Schema validation and token validation functions according to the grant type. The code works basically pretty good, but if I throw an error in the method "checkSchema" I get the full stack trace in the logs, although hapis method replay is supposed to handle that error.

I use bluebird promises, in case that is important.

Here to code:

```
/**
 * checks if the given login informations are right and returns a token response
 * For each strategy you first validate the given payload and next you check if the given payload is ok.
 */
export function authenticate(request, reply) {

    var schema, checkMethod;

    switch (request.payload.grantType) {
        case "password":
            schema = passwordSchema;
            checkMethod = checkPasswordLogin;
            break;
        case "refreshToken":
            schema = refreshTokenSchema;
            checkMethod = checkRefreshTokenLogin;
            break;
        default:
            throw new Error("No valid Grant Type given");
    }
    var promise = Promise
        .try(function() {
            return checkSchema(request.payload, schema);
        })
        .then(function(value) {
            return checkMethod(value);
        })
        .then(function(userInstance) {
            return generateToken(userInstance);
        });

    reply(promise);
}

/**
 * checks if a payload followed a specific schema and throws an error if not
 */
function checkSchema(payload, schema) {
    try {
        Joi.assert(payload, schema);
    } catch (e) {
        throw Boom.create(400, e);
    }

}
```

Here the stack trace in case an Schema fails:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Error: {
  "grantType": "password",
  "username": "John",
  "password" [1]: -- missing --
}

[1] "password" is required
    at Object.exports.create (/server/test-backend/node_modules/boom/lib/index.
js:21:17)
    at checkSchema (/source/api/controllers/app/auth.ts:48:20)
    at /source/api/controllers/app/auth.ts:29:20
    at tryCatcher (/server/test-backend/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:2
6:23)
    at Function.Promise.attempt.Promise.try (/server/test-backend/node_modules/
bluebird/js/main/method.js:31:24)
    at authenticate (/source/api/controllers/app/auth.ts:28:13)
    at Object.internals.handler (/server/test-backend/node_modules/hapi/lib/han
dler.js:94:36)
    at /server/test-backend/node_modules/hapi/lib/handler.js:28:23
    at [object Object].internals.Protect.run (/server/test-backend/node_modules
/hapi/lib/protect.js:56:5)
    at exports.execute (/server/test-backend/node_modules/hapi/lib/handler.js:2
2:22)
    at /server/test-backend/node_modules/hapi/lib/request.js:370:13
    at iterate (/server/test-backend/node_modules/hapi/node_modules/items/lib/i
ndex.js:35:13)
    at done (/server/test-backend/node_modules/hapi/node_modules/items/lib/inde
x.js:27:25)
    at /server/test-backend/node_modules/hoek/lib/index.js:841:22
    at /server/test-backend/node_modules/continuation-local-storage/node_module
s/async-listener/glue.js:188:31
    at process._tickDomainCallback [as _tickCallback] (node.js:486:13)
```

Comment: at any later point are you catching the error?

Comment: What is that `reply` function, where does if come from? Is the source (or documentation) available?

Comment: the reply function comes from [hapijs](http://hapijs.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I currently fixed it by writting the code below. Unfortunally I dont know why if I throw an error in `checkMethod` everything is fine, but if I throw an error in `checkSchema` I need to catch all errors by hand (hapi js is not handling that for me).

```
/**
 * checks if the given login informations are right and returns a token response
 * For each strategy you first validate the given payload and next you check if the given payload is ok.
 */
export function authenticate(request, reply) {

    var schema, checkMethod;

    switch (request.payload.grantType) {
        case "password":
            schema = passwordSchema;
            checkMethod = checkPasswordLogin;
            break;
        case "refreshToken":
            schema = refreshTokenSchema;
            checkMethod = checkRefreshTokenLogin;
            break;
        default:
            throw new Error("No valid Grant Type given");
    }
    var promise = Promise
        .try(function() {
            return checkSchema(request.payload, schema);
        })
        .then(function() {
            return checkMethod(request.payload);
        })
        .then(function(userInstance) {
            return generateToken(userInstance);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            return err;
        });

    reply(promise);
}

/**
 * checks if a payload followed a specific schema and throws an error if not
 */
function checkSchema(payload, schema) {
    var result = Joi.validate(payload, schema);
    if (result.error) {
        return Promise.reject(Boom.wrap(result.error, 400));
    }
    return Promise.resolve(result.value);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't get your problem fully but from what I could understand, you should not throw an error when working with promises. Instead `reject` the promise if there is an error.

Comment: yes rejecting is a good point, but I would need to catch that error then and throw an error via the Boom library in order to get a nice response for the api user and an custom status code.

Comment: i would imagine you could just send an instance of `Error` to Boom on error

Comment: @Safari why don't you try to throw a custom Error object `throw new Error({code: 100, message: ''})` and then in the end of the promise chain, catch it and process the way you want it?

Comment: I tried that already. The problem is if I throw an error, catch it and then create a new Boom Instance. i get again an uncaught error. When I throw errors within the checkMethod function then I dont get uncaught errors

Comment: Also if I reject an error like `return Promise.reject(Boom.wrap(result.error, 400));`. I still get an uncaught exception

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with throwing *inside* a promise. What should be avoided is throwing *instead* of (returning) a promise.